# Max number in a sql table column which starts with specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody help me to find the max number in a SQL table column which starts with a number (ex: 901)

My table column may contain number starts with any digit. So I just need to find the maximum number of all numbers which start with 901 (my number is like length of 9 digits)

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

This will give the maximum number of all.

Thanks

Comment: you can partition the table or index by ranges in later versions of Microsoft SQL server see [https://www.datavail.com/blog/four-things-remember-planning-sql-partitioning/](https://www.datavail.com/blog/four-things-remember-planning-sql-partitioning/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name where column_name => 901000000
```

I think would run a lot faster than converting every value in the result set to a string and then using a `like` clause on it

Comment: I'd also add a check to make sure that column_name is less than 920000000. But otherwise, yes, this a lot less expensive than casting a number to a character and doing string comparison.

Comment: then just add       and column_name < 920000000

Answer (score 0):

this can work, but there might be a better solution too

```
    select MAX(column_name) FROM 
(select * from table_name where to_char(column_name) like '901%' )
```

I am not very familiar with the MS SQL functions - CAST or CONVERT? can be used

Comment: `to_char` is not a SQL Server function ;)